# Django queryset ProgrammingError: column does not exist

Tags: django, django-models

I'm facing a big issue with django.

I'm trying to save object containing `foreignKeys` and 'ManyToMany` but i always get this error

`ProgrammingError: column [columnName] does not exist`

I've made serveral times all migrations but it doesn't works. I have no problem when i work with models that does not contain foreign keys. I have tried to delete the migration folder. It's seems my database doesn't want to update fields. I need to force it to create these column but i don't have any idea.

```
      class Post(models.Model):
post_id = models.CharField(max_length=100,default="")
title = models.CharField(max_length=100,default="")
content = models.TextField(default="")
author = models.ForeignKey(Users, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
comments = models.ManyToManyField(Replies)
numberComments = models.IntegerField(default=0)
date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
updated = models.DateTimeField(null=True)



def __str__(self):
    return self.post_id
```

when i'm trying to retrieve this i have :

`ProgrammingError: column numberComments does not exist`

As i said before i made `makemigrations` and `migrate`, i even  deleted the migration folder.

Any idea ?

Comment: Think carefully before deleting migrations. It can cause your migrations files get out of sync with your database. If you don't have any important data in the database, then you can drop the database, delete the migrations, then running `makemigrations` and then `migrate` should work. If you do have important data in the database, then it can be tricky to get your migrations and database back in sync.

Answer (score -1):

To save a instance of the POST model with foreign key you need to insert the query object.
Code example:

```
user = Users.objects.get(pk = 1)

p = POST(
   title = 'Hello',
   ...
   author = user,
   date = '2018-01-01'
)
p.save()
```

You don't need to create post_id column, django creates one for you automatically, and you can access that using .pk or .id
You neither need numberComments. You should calculate that from comments many to many relation. Well...  you can have this on DB too.

Next, you cannot add a many to many relation on creation. Create the post first as above. Then query the comment you want to add, the add the object to the relation

```
r = Replies.objects.get(pk = 1)
p.comments.add(r)
```

Hope it helps